# Есть ли возможность сделать так, что бы canvas элемент не замораживался в неактивном окне браузера?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Пишу простенькую игрушку, используя canvas и чистый js. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: если свернуть браузер, перейти на другую вкладку, то canvas замораживается и не двигается. (Не вызывается `requestAnimationFrame()`)

Я понимаю, что так устроен браузер, но, может всё-таки есть решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `setInterval` вместо `requestAnimationFrame`.